# Can we say that $x=0$ is a double root of $f(x) = (e^x-1)(\ln( x+1))$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, soft-question, terminology, roots

Let $$f(x) = (e^x-1)(\ln( x+1))$$

So far , I've only seen examples of textbooks referencing repeated roots if we can write the function with linear factors raised to some natural exponent ( like if $a$ is a repeated root , then we can write the function as $(x-a)^{m+1}g(x), m\in\mathbb N$). But in above example, the factors are not linear polynomials.

So ,
Is it correct to say that $x=0$ is a repeated root of $f$ or not?

**Context:**

I'm confirming the terminology because currently I'm studying derivatives. My teacher said that functions having repeated roots are always differentiable at that point with derivative equal to $0$ . That's why I asked question whether above type of functions come into that category so that the property of differentiability could be extended.

Comment: But f(1)≠0, did you mean x=0 instead?

Comment: @Divide1918  I'm sorry. I'll fix it.

Comment: @FishDrownedI'm sorry. I'll fix it.

Comment: What makes you doubt that $x=0$ is a repeated root of $f$?

Comment: "I've only seen examples of textbooks referencing repeated roots if we can write the function with linear factors raised to some natural exponent" if you could quote the exact definition that'd be helpful. Nevertheless, compare e.g. with [this definition](https://math.fel.cvut.cz/mt/txtb/3/txe4ba3c.htm) or [this definition in PierreCarre's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226962/root-multiplicity-for-non-polynomial-function).

Comment: @FishDrowned Because the $f$ does not have factors in linear polynomial form.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I had never seen an exact/precise definition before.  Thanks for the link and clarification. So , can we say any function having repeated root must be differentiable at it's repeated root point ?

Comment: @An_Elephant Yes, this is easy to prove by first principles and the (extended) definition of a repeated root. In fact, the derivative will be equal to $0$. In your example, [you can see this here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivative+of+%28e%5Ex-1%29ln%28x%2B1%29+at+x%3D0).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer What do you mean by extended definition? Thanks

Comment: @An_Elephant Good point : your definition/understanding of "repeated root" is that "we can write the function with linear factors raised to some natural exponent", where "the factors are linear polynomials" (borrowing your words). If you notice, the definitions in those posts don't use polynomials anywhere so they're more general/extended definitions that apply in more cases, like the function you gave.

Comment: I've never heard someone use the phrase "repeated roots" for a non-algebraic function, but I guess Robert's interpretation as $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$ seems reasonable.

Comment: @pancini Thanks. Suppose ,$ f = (x-1)^2$,  for $x = 1$ and $f = 2$ otherwise. But this function has a repeated root at $x=1$ but it's not differentiable.

Comment: The root of that function wouldn't satisfy either (suggested) definition of repeated root.

Comment: Isn't there a problem with functions like $(x-1)^\frac{7}{3}$? This is zero and is differentiable with zero gradient at $x=1$, and can be written as a product $(x-1)^2(x-1)^\frac{1}{3}$, but I wouldn't want to say that there is a double root at $x=1$.

Comment: Also, the function defined as $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ for $x \ne 0$ and $0$ at $x=0$. This has zero derivatives of all orders at $x=0$, but does it have a double root? I wonder if the definition you need is "has a Taylor series at $x=a$ with the first two coefficients zero". It definitely does make sense to talk about double roots in this case, but it may be possible to widen the class of functions for which it's appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed say that $0$ is a repeated root of this function.  More generally, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable functions which both have a root at $x = a$, then $h(x) = f(x) g(x)$ has a repeated root there, because $h(a) = 0$ and
$h'(a) = f(a) g'(a) + f'(a) g(a) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks sir. Sir, so any function ( not necessarily polynomial ) is always differentiable at it's repeated root point ?

Comment: By the definition I'm using, $f(x)$ has a repeated root at $x=a$ if  $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(a) = 0$.  The last equation requires that $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

Comment: Thanks sir. I was initially concerned about differentiability with the help of repeated roots but it seems like it's the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \lim_{ x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=1$ so $\text{ord}_{x=0}(f)=2 $, i.e., $f$ has a double zero in $x = 0$.

EDIT.
$$e^x-1= x\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$$ and
$$\ln(x+1)= x\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{n}$$
therefore $f(x)=x^2g(x)$ with $g(0) \neq 0$

Answer (score -1):

Try to take the limit of $f(x)$ divided by $x^2$ at $x=0$. If it exists and it is different from 0, then $f(x)$ has a double root at $x=0$.